# Problem with installing Nvidia driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, ubuntu-drivers

I was trying to change my NVidia driver to 435.21 with cuda 10.1 (Ubuntu 18.04) to work on Tensorflow-GPU. After rebooting, I could not able to enter normally to the Ubuntu, I think the driver is not installed well or there some missing or conflicting packages. So, I used recovery mode to access, then I tried to remove and purge Nvidia files and install it again, but I faced the following error:

[Pic1 - Error1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwvVO.png)

[Pic2 - Error1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivUHx.png)

Also, I used “fix broken” command to fix broken packages but it gives me this error.

[Pic3 - Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QJs8.png)

Now I am stuck. I can’t remove any files or fix or upgrade. Can someone tell me how can I fix the problem, please?

Thank you in advance

Some details:

- Device: Alienware Area 51m
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- GPU: GeFroce RTX 2080
- Previous driver version: 440.64
- Previous CUDA version: 10.2

Comment: You need to remove your previous driver first before installing another version of the NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` . Please also do not add screenshots copy and paste the output instead.

Comment: You could have also done `sudo apt remove --autoremove nvidia-driver-440` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often solve issues like this by using `dpkg --force-all`. Any conflicting packages, do

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libnvidia-extra-440:amd64
```

repeat it until the offending packages are gone, then do

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to install the packages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and quick response. It works well ^_^